# CakePHP 3 losing Auth Session

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I am using Auth Session in CakePHP.

```
'Session' => [
    'timeout' => 0,
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_secure' => false,
        'session.cookie_lifetime' => 0
    ]
],
```

Already configured this in tha app.php but still getting logged out after few minutes.

Although Session persists when closing Browser. So i think its just a time related problem.

Comment: i also checked the session.gc_maxlifetime in my php.ini, so thatas not the problem too. To be honest, i dont exactly know how to debug this problem

Comment: I have similar problem. Cookie is set for one year but session is lost after about an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having requirement to increase session timeout in cakphp 2.5
the following code worked for me in 2.5 you can give this a try

```
//FILE: config/core.php

Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'cookie' => 'my_app',
        'timeout'  => 500,  // 8 hours + 20 min, user will be logged in till 8 hours.
        )
    );
```