# CakePhp 3 keep auth session

Tags: php, session, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to log user automatically in cakephp 3 after closed the browser. I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539445/cakephp-3-losing-auth-session) but it doesn't change anything.
The session with "my-app" name exist but users doesn't automatically log.

My code in AppController:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Usagers',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Admin',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'storage' => [
            'className' => 'Session',
            'key' => 'Auth.User',
        ],
    ]);
```

my code in usersController :

```
public function login()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

I don't know why my session is not keeped.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: what is your session configuration on app.php file

Comment: Try to add     'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => 31556926
    ] in the end of app.php file

Comment: If you want to log user automatically you need to set user in cookies and in      login action check if user exist in cookies if not set user data in cookies else redirect in main page.

Comment: i already try your first comment First ! And when i close the browser the session is closed.  I think you'r right , i need to deal with cookies. I'll try it.

Comment: Without a cookie, how could it know which session to load?

Answer (score 0):

Using security and Csrf protection?

If so, you will need to set expiration time in both. You can increase sesstion time, but the Csrf cookie will be gone when browser close as default.

Example for 7days expiration using CakePHP 3

in app.php:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'CookieName',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_lifetime' => 604800 // 7 days
    ],
    'timeout' => 10080 // 7 days
],
```

in AppController.php

```
$this->loadComponent('Csrf',['secure'=>true,'expiry'=> strtotime("+7 day")]);
```